# Installing Rails on Mac OSX Yosemite ("application" invalid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I've been following the amazingly convoluted path to installing Ruby (and Rails) on a Mac (OSX Yosemite). I used the Terminal to install rbenv. Then I tried to install Rails,  following the instructions @ http://rubyonrails.org/download/

Terminal displays a bunch of code that suggests the operation was a success. But when I navigate to http://localhost:3000 I get the message "This webpage is not available."

Taking another look at my Terminal code, I see a couple apparent problems at the very beginning:

```
rails new path/to/your/new/application
Invalid application name application. Please give a name which does not    match one of the reserved rails words.
My-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ cd path/to/your/new/application
-bash: cd: path/to/your/new/application: No such file or directory
My-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ rails server
```

Can anyone explain what's going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what is happening is that you've named your application 'application', and this is what's causing errors in your rails setup. 'application' is a keyword used internally by Rails, and is probably throwing it off.

Comment: Also, `path/to/your/new/application` should be replaced with the path where you actually want your application. This should be relative to the directory you are currently in, or an absolute path from root (`/`)

Comment: Yikes, how did I miss that? So it looks like I just need to replace path/to/your/new/application with an actual path. But I'm still confused; I'm not sure how to designate a path to an application. Most of my software programs are stored in a folder named Applications. So I "replaced path/to/your/new/applications" with "Applications/Rail" and pasted that in Terminal. The command was processed, but I can't find a folder named Rails in my Applications folder, and nothing displays at http://locahost:3000

Comment: OK, I just saw your other note and changed Applications/Rails to /Applications/Rails. I now see a webpage at locahost:3000.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used rvm instead of rbenv. It's easy to set up on Mac OSX Yosemite using curl, and I've never had any problems installing Rails on it. Are you tied to rbenv for some reason? If not, give rvm a try : https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: I've Google'd several resources, and there was some discussion of rbenv vs rvm. I can't even remember why rbenv was recommended over rvm, but it seemed to be the more popular choice. But if I can't even install it, then maybe rvm is the way to go after all. ;)